# Basic Windows Command don't work in .cmd file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

Here is my `dummyScript.cmd` file contents-

```
@echo off

set logfile=LogFile.log

echo Deleting backed up databases and folder > %logfile%
RMDIR /S /Q dummyFolder
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo Unable to delete the back-ups. Please check the log file '%logfile%'
    call start notepad %logfile%
    exit %ERRORLEVEL%
)

echo Copying another backed up folder from a remote server... >> %logfile%
xcopy /Y "\\dummyRemoteServer\c$\dummy\folder" "C:\Dummy\Folder" >> %logfile%
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo Unable to the backed up folder from remote server. Please check the log file '%logfile%'.
    call start notepad %logfile%
    exit %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

When I run that as Administrator, nothing happens. When I run the script from command prompt, it gives me this error message-

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

OS: Windows 10

Many people have posted this, but the solutions didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove `@echo off`, run the script from the command line, and see which line causes the error. The only weird thing I see is that you've used `call start` instead of just `start`.

Comment: I've tested `call start`. It seems to be working for me. Alright, I'll remove `@echo off` and check once.

Comment: It's not wrong per se, just strange since you don't have a reason to do it that way. I also have a theory that the script is saved with an encoding other than ANSI, which can cause some issues.

Comment: That's quite strange. I started a fresh command prompt and ran the script again. It worked. Also, I checked the encoding. It was UTF-8. But it seems to be working for me now. Thanks.

Comment: The UTF-8 BOM sometimes causes issues, so that could be relevant.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind and change the Encoding and try if I face any such issues again in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and run the batch script from there rather than double-clicking its icon, so you can review potential error messages; prior to that, replace `exit` by `exit /B` to just exit the script but not the hosting Command Prompt instance…